# How to Export HTML DIV contents to powerpoint slide in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, powerpoint

I am trying to export all the contents of  div tag into ppt file. I am able to do it for doc and excel because there is an open xml format for word and excel. i do the following things for ppt but didn't get the right result.
here is my html code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="demo" runat=server>
        <h1>Click the button to Export</h1>
        <h3>This page contain a heading,paragraph and a table</h3>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="export" OnClick="Export_to_ppt" Text="Export" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
```

here is cs code

```
 string elements = demo.InnerHtml;
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.ppt");  
 Response.Write(elements);
 Response.End();
```

In my result, each content show but the html tags also showed. But i just want to see this as it viewed in html page. Each content also printed in different slide but i want see those in one slide.

please help me with this.